# Automate copying new file in specific folder to clipboard

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard, automator, gif

I'm using a macOS app to create GIFs (called [GifFox](https://gifox.app/)) but the app does not offer a feature to auto-save to clipboard. However, I can define the location the GIF will be saved to. How can I create an automation that:

1. listens for new files in this folder and auto-copies them to the clipboard (preferred UX)
2. that copies the newest file in a folder to the clipboard after I execute a certain shortcut (less optimal).

I know I can trigger scripts via Automator. I'm specifically looking for a script that can accomplish this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ignore the community bot.  The question is fine, and perfectly easy to understand.  Did you search on StackExchange.com for questions pertaining to _"Folder Action Scripts"_ ?  Having answered a gajillion questions myself very much like this one, you can find something very similar to get you started.  When you reach a hurdle, you can update this question with your code, and we can help you over the hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

You can save this following **AppleScript** code in **Script Editor.app** as "File_To_Clipboard.scpt" (or whatever name you want) to your /Users/**your_short_name**/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/ folder (you need to create this directory if it doesn't exist yet).

```
property theFile : missing value

on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    --  Called after items have been added to a folder
    
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  theNewItems is a list of references to the items added to the folder 
    
    set theFile to POSIX path of theNewItems
    set the clipboard to POSIX file theFile
    
end adding folder items to
```

Then in **Finder**, right click the Folder that your GIF files will be saved to and select **Folder Actions Setup...** then select your new "File_To_Clipboard.scpt" file to attach to that Folder.

Now anytime a file is added to that Folder, that file will be copied to your clipboard. (original answer by [wch1zpink](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/210407/wch1zpink) [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446521/automate-copying-new-file-in-specific-folder-to-clipboard/446536#446536))